# num_rows returns no value

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following code to find the number of rows returned:

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM list WHERE queue = 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,1");

$rowcount = $results->num_rows;
echo $rowcount;
```

As you can see, the results are limited to 1 row, and when I run this query in SQL it returns 1 row just fine. But in PHP the `$rowcount` doesn't return any value at all.

Any ideas what might be wrong? I get no error.

Comment: I know that with `$wpdb->query`, you can get the number of results using `$wpdb->num_rows`. Not sure about `get_results` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `count($results)` since the method `$wpdb->get_results` returns a array of objects/arrays.

Another way to get the number of rows is to use `$wpdb->num_rows`. Apparently this works for 
`$wpdb->get_results`.

From the docs (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), it says the following about get_results:

> Generic, multiple row results can be pulled from the database with
>   get_results. The function returns the entire query result as an array.
>   Each element of this array corresponds to one row of the query result
>   and, like get_row, can be an object, an associative array, or a
>   numbered array. If no matching rows are found, or if there is a
>   database error, the return value will be an empty array. If your
>   $query string is empty, or you pass an invalid $output_type, NULL will
>   be returned.

Comment: Your answer before you edited worked. But you are right. It returned a list of arrays. But this answer worked fine as well. Seems like my original source was wrong.

Comment: Ah, that's cool. I wasn't sure if `$wpdb->num_rows` would work. I'll add that too since it's not clear from the docs.